# Cannot install Fragment Image Viewer on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ppa, 14.04

I opened Software Center and tried to install Fragment. I clicked `more info`, then the `Buy` button, logged in to Ubuntu successfully.

The installation never ends and nothing gets installed.

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get HTTP 401 errors regarding private PPAs which contain Fragment.

> W: ... https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/fragment/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages HttpError401
>
> W: ... https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/fragment/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages HttpError401

I have also posted on Launchpad [here](http://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/247218).

Comment: This seems to be an issue specifically on 14.04(installs seamlessly on 12.04 at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.

I opened `/etc/apt/auth.conf` and changed the username.

The username stored there was my Yahoo mail username and I changed it to my Launchpad username.

It probably happened because I switched my email from Yahoo to Gmail for my Ubuntu One account. It didn't work with Gmail username either.

So opening this https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/fragment/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fragment/ in any browser and entering the login and password from `/etc/apt/auth.conf` allows to download the `deb` packages.

So apps from Ubuntu One can be manually installed on other distros (like Linux Mint).

Answer (score 1):

Try it again i tried installing, it worked fine and installed

They might have updated their ppa for Trusty, i did not get any error with "sudo apt-get update"

Answer (score 1):

The 401 Unauthorized error is an HTTP status code that means the page you were trying to access can not be loaded until you first log on with a valid user ID and password. If you have just logged on and received the 401 Unauthorized error, it means that the credentials you entered were invalid for some reason. As you surmised, changing your credentials caused this problem.